# node-red: How to edit the subflow which is packaged as module and imported into my flow

Tags: node-red

Is there any way that I can edit the subflow node which imported as a package module.
Currently I am not able to edit packaged subflow, If not edit atleast view is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

Once it's packaged, it becomes a node not a subflow.

Comment: As a user I agree edit or view is not required, but as an owner of that module or node I should be able to edit or view the packaged node -> is there any way for that

Comment: You edit the original flow you used to create the packaged subflow node and then repackage it. Packaging subflows is a one way process.